# How do I set up a choice column in Windows Sharepoint Services 3 SP2 that contains the date/time and user identity that selected a particular choice?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, wss

We are using WSS 3 SP2. I'd like to preface this by saying that while I have been programming for some time, I have not done any Sharepoint development before now, so I am very much a newbie in that respect.

Basically what we have is a Sharepoint wiki that contains support documentation about each of the various applications throughout our organization. Each application has a wiki page containing some of the more pertinent info (vendor support #, etc), and these wiki pages are created from a template.

Currently, there is one "choice" column on the template that lists all of our department work groups, and users can edit the individual wiki pages to check off their particular work group after they've verified that the relevant wiki page information is correct. Example:

> [Checkbox] Help Desk
>
> [Checkbox] Programming
>
> [Checkbox] Networking

What I've been tasked with is adding functionality to the template column that does the following:

- list  the date that each checkbox was checked
- Indicate the user identity that checked the checkbox (logged on username is fine)
- display the percentage of checkboxes that have been checked

Example:

> **Application Verification: 66%**
>
> [Checkbox] Help Desk - verified by JohnDoe on 8/26/10
>
> [Checkbox] Programming - Unverified
>
> [Checkbox] Networking - verified by JaneDoe on 7/21/10

I have been playing around with web parts trying to get my feet wet, but I don't know enough about Sharepoint yet to understand if a new web part is the way to go or if I can extend the choice column to do this.

What is the best way to accomplish this with Sharepoint? Can someone point me in the proper direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction I would start in would be developing a custom field, that would store your info internally in some sort of custom structure (XML, comma-separated, whatever). Then in the render control you will need to serialize and deserialize this value into your representation. Take a look at the following tutorial to get you started on custom fields:
http://vspug.com/nicksevens/2007/08/31/create-custom-field-types-for-sharepoint/

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I needed to get started.